# Core Bluetooth Framework Connection Latency xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-bluetooth

I'm new to `CoreBluetooth.framework`, how can I change the connection latency parameter of my connection? I've found this in CBPeripheralmanager.h file:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, CBPeripheralManagerConnectionLatency) {
CBPeripheralManagerConnectionLatencyLow = 0,
CBPeripheralManagerConnectionLatencyMedium,
CBPeripheralManagerConnectionLatencyHigh } NS_ENUM_AVAILABLE(NA, 6_0);
```

How can I add to my code the right setting? I want to set `CBPeripheralManagerConnectionLatencyHigh`

Thank you very much.

Comment: `setDesiredConnectionLatency:forCentral:`?

Comment: `CBPeripheralManager` has a method `(void)setDesiredConnectionLatency:(CBPeripheralManagerConnectionLatency)latency forCentral:(CBCentral *)central`. That could be what you're looking for.